# How to use localStorage to cache button result?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that I am making completely out of JS.

I want to save whether it was in a true or false state so that if a user leaves the page the button will be in the same state when they return. I'd like to use localStorage but I'm relatively new to JS so they may be a better solution.

Current Code:

```
var btn;
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.onclick =  function() {myFunction()};
btn.style.height = "100%";
btn.style.width = "98%";
btn.style.border = "0px";
btn.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";  
btn.id = "toggle";


document.getElementById("button").appendChild(btn);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('notepad').classList.toggle('hide'); return false
}
```

Edit Code:

```
window.onload = function initBt(){
var buttonState = localStorage.getItem('mybutton');
if ( null !== buttonState )
{
buttonState && document.getElementById('notepad').classList.add('hide');
}
}
var btn;


var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.onclick =  function() {myFunction()};
btn.style.height = "100%";
btn.style.width = "98%";
btn.style.border = "0px";
btn.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";  


btn.id = "toggle";


document.getElementById("button").appendChild(btn);


function myFunction() {
var bt = document.getElementById('notepad');
bt.classList.toggle('hide');
localStorage.setItem('mybutton', bt.classList.contains('hide'))
return false;
}
```

Comment: Please try with localStorage first. Then if you have problems come back and show what you tried

Comment: @charlietfl I would but I have only seen it used for text values not results, so I'm not sure how I would make it work. But I'll keep working at it.

Comment: So you store different values for the  different states of your button and then check what it is on page load and react accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following functions in youir code to store and retrieve the button state:

[localStorage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
function store(key, data)
{
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
}

function retrieve(key)
{
   var data = localStorage.getItem(key);
   return data ? JSON.parse(data) : null;
}

function remove(key)
{
   localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

usage examples:

```
store('mybutton', buttonState);
var buttonState = retrieve('mybutton');
if ( buttonState !== null )
{
   /* set button State*/
}
else
{
   /* state has not been saved before, initialise */
}
```

**NOTE** since `localStorage` can handle **ONLY string values**, we use `JSON.stringify` when saving to make a string out of data and `JSON.parse` when retrieving in order to store and retrieve arbitrary data (that are of course [JSON valid structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON))

For your updated question try the following (it would be more helpfull if the whole html structure was added since some elements are missing, but anyway):

```
// include the needed localStorage manipulation methods
function store(key, data)
{
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
}
function retrieve(key)
{
   var data = localStorage.getItem(key);
   return data ? JSON.parse(data) : null;
}
function remove(key)
{
   localStorage.removeItem(key);
}

// create and initialise the button
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.onclick =  function() {myFunction()};
btn.style.height = "100%";
btn.style.width = "98%";
btn.style.border = "0px";
btn.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";  
btn.id = "toggle";
document.getElementById("button").appendChild(btn);
var buttonState = retrieve('mybutton');

// make sure at this point element with id="notepad" exists on page
if ( null !== buttonState )
{
    buttonState && document.getElementById('notepad').classList.add('hide');
}

function myFunction() {
var bt = document.getElementById('notepad');
bt.classList.toggle('hide');
store('mybutton', bt.classList.contains('hide'));
return false;
}
```

For a flexible caching library for web/browser that can support a variety of storage mechanisms (and also support for server-side php and node.js) check [Unicache](https://github.com/foo123/Unicache) (ps. I am the author)

There are of course other libraries as well (eg [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage))

Comment: How would I go about representing the state of the button?

Comment: it depends on oyur application, possibly a simple `true` or `false` value may bbe enough (ie button set or not set). Then simply store this value and when retrieving update the button accordingly

Comment: if answer solves your problem please do accept it. People who answer on SO will help but still need to be recognised for their efforts

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work, I messed around with it for a while but never got it working. Thanks for the help :) Also are the retrieve and store that you used part of a library?

Comment: @STOAM, store/retrieve functions are not part of a library but you can check linked libraries in my answer which use similar methods or if you dont want the overhead of a full library simply use these helpful functions. Where did you get stuck exactly, maybe I can help? I suspect you did not place the store and retrieve calls in the appropriate places in your code so as to correctly store and retrieve the button state..

Comment: I switched out the store/retrieve because they were not being recognized.
I placed the edited code in my original post.

Comment: @STOAM, updated answer, it should be fine however I am not sure if the hide class is on the button or on element with id="notepad" and whether this element already exists or is dynamicaly created. So make sure to run this code when element already exists on page, else update your question with information aboput this element. Some information is missing from your question

Comment: Thanks, The element is created and just is set to display: none. I also see what I wasn't including, I'm an idiot. Thanks for helping me out.